# How to open android studio in different workspace in ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-studio, command, workspace, ubuntu-16.10

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 i have enabled workspaces as you can see in below screen-shot so that we can work in different workspaces

[image]

But when i switched to different workspace and trying to launch studio by command **studio.sh** i am getting message "Already Running". As i have already launched android studio in different workspace.

So my question is how can i launch android studio in different workspace? As i am unable to launch android studio in different workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

When you start Android Studio, it will open in workspace you are currently in. Later you can move it from one workspace to another by dragging it in Workspace Switcher (you will find it in your toolbar on the left when workspaces are enabled).

Or, if you want it to run in specific, non current workspace, you can check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87002/how-can-i-get-a-startup-application-to-run-in-another-workspace-other-than-1).